# BeautifulSoup XML parsing strangely placed number

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have an xml file I am parsing with BeautifulSoup.

The top of the file looks like this

```
<search_results count="1448">
<query>genentech</query>
<!-- Additional study fields may be added over time -->
<study rank="1">
<title>A Study in Participants Previously Enrolled in a Genentech− and/or F. 
Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd-Sponsored Atezolizumab Study (IMbrella A)</title>
<recruitment open="Y">Not yet recruiting</recruitment>
<study_results>No Results Available</study_results>
<conditions>
<condition>Cancer</condition>
</conditions>
<interventions>
<intervention type="Drug">Atezolizumab</intervention>
</interventions>
<url>https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT03148418</url>
</study>
```

How do I get the search_results count number out of that? I've tried soup.search_results.count, that didn't work. Neither did soup.count.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what about trying `soup.search_results['count']`? src: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes

Comment: HOLY CRAP THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've been stuck on this for like 3 hours